# Lumen 7 controllers bug

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am using lumen 7 framework.
I had a bug. In the web.php file I put:

```
$router->get('/getAll/{param1:[0-9]+|2A|2B}/{param2:[0-9]+}', 'TestController@getAll');
```

So, in the TestController, I create the function like that :

```
  public function getAll($param1, $parm2)
{
    ....
}
```

The isssue is :

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #1 [  $param2 ]] in class App\Http\Controllers\TestController

I did some tests, I add this bloc to provider, but it didn't work.

```
$this->app->singleton(\Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory::class, function() {
return new \Laravel\Lumen\Http\ResponseFactory();
```

});

Also, I checked if I had done something wrong in the web.php file but I changed the function in the controllers to :

```
      public function getAll($param1)
    {
        $parm2=1;
        ....
    }
```

and it works fine.

How can I fix this bug, because in the url I need the two params.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that the names in controller and in the route was not the same.
The names in the controller was a little different from the route.
I did a upgrade from lumen 5.6 to lumen 7.0 and I thinks since Lumen 5.8 the names must be the same.

Comment: You mean namespace got changed or something?

Comment: No, just in the web.php file the url was 
$router->get('/getAll/{param1:[0-9]+|2A|2B}/{param2:[0-9]+}', 'TestController@getAll');
and in the controller it was like : 
  public function getAll($param1, $parm2)
{
    ....
}
The difference is the route it is param2 and in controller parm2, a little difference juste it lacks "a" but this was changed since version 5.8 (I am not sure)

Comment: I was reviving an old project and after the upgrade to Lumen 7 I got this error and spent quite a long time trying to figure it out but yea it turns out the parameter on the route has to match the one on the controller. I think you should mark it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks - that was the hint I really needed!

Answer (score 1):

In route, you're passing only one param that's why you're getting this error.

```
$router->get('/getAll/{param1:[0-9]+|2A|2B}/{param2:[0-9]+}/{param2:[0-9]+|2A|2B}/{param2:[0-9]+}', 'TestController@getAll');
```

In controller.

```
public function getAll($param1, $param2)
{
    ....
}
```